# Styled highlighted text inside table cell

Tags: html, css

I need to highlight text only in table cell so the highlight has some padding around the text and with rounded corners like in picture. How can i achieve this?[image]

Comment: How are you approaching this? add some html and css that you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need another element inside the td

```css
     td > div {
      background: orange;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div>
                my text
           </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```